# Removing all special characters from an entire dataframe but keeping factor level definitions

Tags: r, gsub, xgboost, model.matrix

'm trying to remove special characters e.g. "-","/",")","(" etc entirely from my dataframe. However my dataframe only contains one observation as it's feeding into a model that will be used in production. I've defined the factor levels explicitly for the data frame.

I've tried the following:

```
sanitize_string <- function(string){
  gsub('\\s+', "_", string) %>%
    gsub("[(]", "_", .) %>%
    gsub("[)]", "_", .) %>%
    gsub("[/]", "_", .) %>%
    gsub("[-]", "_", .)}
```

and then:

```
 df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(dataframe) sapply(dataframe, sanitize_string)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But when I do this, I'm loose my factor levels, it just sees every factor as having one level, which causes problems later when I try to get predictions from my model as the sparse.model.matrix needs 2 or more levels for each factor, but really in production, it will only be sent one observation.

Thanks.

Here is my dataframe:

````
 $ children_under16                : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1
 $ ft_employment_status            : Factor w/ 5 levels "Employed","Full-Time Education(Student)",..: 1
 $ fuel_type                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "D","P": 2
 $ homeowner                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2
 $ marital_status                  : Factor w/ 6 levels "Married","Separated",..: 1
 $ overnight_loc                   : Factor w/ 7 levels "In a private Driveway",..: NA
 $ usage_type                      : Factor w/ 3 levels "CLASS_1","SDPC",..: 1
 $ licence_type                    : Factor w/ 3 levels "UK","European",..: 1
 $ yad_relationship_to_policyholder: Factor w/ 8 levels "Spouse","No_YAD",..: 1
 $ A                          : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","5","3",..: 1
 $ B                          : Factor w/ 19 levels "C","E","Q","D",..: 1
 $ C                           : Factor w/ 63 levels "11","19","58",..: 1
 $ region                          : Factor w/ 12 levels "Yorkshire and The Humber",..: 1
 $ D                      : Factor w/ 28 levels "Semi-Detached Suburbia",..: 27
 $ E                   : Factor w/ 77 levels "Families in Terraces and Flats",..: 77
 $ F                 : Factor w/ 9 levels "Suburbanites",..: 1
 $ industry_band                   : Factor w/ 18 levels "13","14","15",..: 14
 $ occ_band_goco                   : Factor w/ 17 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 2
 $ transmission                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","M": 2
 $ vehicle_make                    : Factor w/ 19 levels "OTHER","AUDI",..: 1
 $ vehicle_type           : Factor w/ 17 levels "Mid Exec Saloon/Estate/Coupe",..: 1
 $ rural_urban                     : Factor w/ 19 levels "Urban major conurbation",..: 2
 $ water_company                   : Factor w/ 23 levels "Affinity Water",..: 23
 $ seats                           : Factor w/ 6 levels "-99","2","4",..: ```
````

Comment: Could you please give `head(df)` and `str(df)`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? Would love to re-create the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize the `levels` of the factor, rather than the column. This will preserve the order the levels are in---though it will create an error if your sanitization takes two levels that were different and makes them the same. I would just do a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if(is.factor(df[[i]])) {
    levels(df[[i]]) = sanitize_string(levels(df[[i]]))
  }
}
```

I can't test this on the structure you've posted, but if you have problems please share some data with `dput()` so I can copy/paste it (e.g., `dput(df[1:10, ])`, or some other small subset that illustrates the problem) and I'll be happy to test and refine.